# Checking if str1 can be re-arranged as str2 wth JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There are two strings called `str1` and `str2` and I'm trying to check if str1 can be re-arranged as str2.

FOR EXAMPLE: lets say str1 = "aabbcamaomsccdd" and str2="commas".
Is it possible to write the word "commas" out of "str1"

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {

  let arr=[]; 
  let str1arr =  str1.split("");
  let str2arr =  str2.split("");
  let j=0;
  
  for(let i=0; i<str1.length; i++){
    if(str1arr[i]==str2arr[j]){
      arr.push(str1arr[i]);
      str1arr=str1arr.splice(i,1);
      j++;
      i=0;
      
    }
    
  }if(arr.toString()===str2arr.toString()){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
    }
```

What I tried basically if `str1arr[i]==str2arr[j]` it will put the `str1arr[i]` value on a new array called `arr` and at the end it will compare `str2` and the `arr` and return True or False.

The reason why I used  `str1arr=str1arr.splice(i,1);` to delete the `i` after the match is because the for loop is reseting it self to check from the "i=0" each time `i` and `j` matches and that `i` would match with other duplicate letters (I hope thats what it does atleast :D).

It is an internet question and im not passing the tests. I only pass if the result is FALSE.

I want to know what I'm doing and thinking wrong here. Its not performance efficent too so any comment on that would be great too.

Comment: Does sorting both strings and comparing work?

Comment: You should say that only portion of the string1 is tested, not the whole string, because it changes the task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823054/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-true-if-a-portion-of-str1-can-be-rearranged

Comment: I dont understand what it means by the portion of str1. Str1 is basically scrambled letters like str1="aabbcamaomsccdd" and str2 is = "commas" lets say. Question is can make out the word commas out of the letters inside the str1.

Answer (score 2):

You could take arrays and sort them and check each character of the second string/array against the first one.

```js
function compare([...a], [...b]) {
    a.sort();
    return b.sort().every((i => v => {
        while (i < a.length && a[i] !== v) i++;
        return a[i++] === v;
    })(0));
}

console.log(compare("aabbcamaomsccdd", "commas")); //  true
console.log(compare("aabbcamaomccdd", "commas"));  // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just check that both strings contain the same chars like so:

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
    var s1 = str1.split('');
    var s2 = str2.split('');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
      const idx = s1.indexOf(s2[i]);
      if (idx === -1) {
        return false;
      }
      s1.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return s1.length === 0;
}

console.log(scramble('xcab1c', 'abxcc1'));
```

Comment: This doesnt work if st1 and st2 doenst have the same length.

Comment: of course it does! if s2 is longer then, at some point, you'll get -1 in `indexOf()`. If s1 is longer then you'll get false at `return s1.length === 0`

Comment: I actually dont know why your code fails the test it looks fine to me. But I changed the if to `if(idx>1){ s1.splice(idx,1)` and put an `else` that returns false after the `if`. Now it passes the tests but still fails from the performance test and times out long stirngs.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the frequency of each character in your first string. Below I have used `.reduce()` to build an object with key-value pairs, where the key represents a character from your `s1` string and the value is how many times it appears. You can then loop through the characters in `s2` and check that every character appears in the frequency map. When you see a character you can subtract one from the value from the frequency object to signify that the character has been "used". If the `.every()` callback returns a falsy value (such as 0 for the value), then the result will be `false`, as your string can't be re-arranged:

```js
const scramble = (s1, s2) => {
  const s1Freq = [...s1].reduce((o, c) => ({...o, [c]: (o[c] || 0) +1}), {});
  return [...s2].every(char => s1Freq[char]--); 
}

console.log(scramble("aabbcamaomsccdd", "commas")); // true
console.log(scramble("abc321", "123")); // true
console.log(scramble("a3b2c11", "1231")); // true
console.log(scramble("a", "a")); // true
console.log(scramble("xyz", "xyt")); // false
```